# Sweet Home 3D doesn't start

Tags: unity, software-installation

I have been using Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit. I recently installed Sweet Home 3D from Software Center. But it doesn't start after installation even after restarting the system. Trying to start it from Terminal gives the following message.

```
neo@neo-OEM:~$ sweethome3d
[warning] /usr/bin/sweethome3d: Unable to locate /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/javaws.jar in /usr/share/java
Java 3D: implicit antialiasing enabled
^Cneo@neo-OEM:~$ ^C
```

I tried to search java-6-sun in Software Center but could not find it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which version of Sweet Home 3D did you install?

Comment: Sweethome3d 4.3+dfsg-1. It started working fine after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 but again when I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

I recommended you, install latest version of Sweet Home 3D
Download [32 bit version](http://cznic.dl.sourceforge.net/project/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D/SweetHome3D-4.4/SweetHome3D-4.4-linux-x86.tgz)

Download [64 bit version](http://cznic.dl.sourceforge.net/project/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D/SweetHome3D-4.4/SweetHome3D-4.4-linux-x64.tgz)

32-bit or 64-bit? Check it out by going to System Settings -> Details. Check out if there’s a new release at [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sweethome3d/files/SweetHome3D/)

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal. When it opens, paste the below command and hit enter to extract the package to `/opt/`:

   `cd /opt/ && sudo tar -zxvf ~/Downloads/SweetHome3D-4.4-linux-*.tgz`

   (In the command, you may replace `SweetHome3D-4.4-linux-*.tgz` with the exact package name.)
2. Now you’re able to launch SweetHome3D via:

   `/opt/SweetHome3D-4.4/SweetHome3D`

#### If everything goes OK. Let’s create a launcher for it so that you can start it from Unity Dash or Launcher.

In a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, run command:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/sweethome3d-4.4.desktop`

It will create a config file and open it with Gedit text editor.

Paste below content into the file and save it.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Sweet Home 3D 4.4
GenericName=Interior 2D design application with 3D preview
GenericName[de]=Innenraumplaner
Comment=Interior design Java application for quickly choosing and placing furniture on a house 2D plan drawn by the end-user with a 3D preview
Exec=/opt/SweetHome3D-4.4/SweetHome3D
Icon=sweethome3d
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=com-eteks-sweethome3d-SweetHome3D
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Graphics;2DGraphics;3DGraphics;
Keywords=interior;design;2D;3D;home;house;furniture;java;
```

You may grab a logo icon from web. Name it **sweethome3d.png** and put it under **/usr/share/icons/**.

Once done, you’re able to open Sweet Home 3D 4.4 from Unity Dash result.

Comment: Thanks KashiyA for the suggestion but default-jre is already installed.

Comment: @Neo I have updated my answer.

Comment: Replace 4.4 with 5.4 and it still works like a charm on the latest version.